# Random location with google street view

Tags: google-street-view, google-maps-static-api

Is there any way to get a random location on Google Street View Image API?
If I try a location that corresponds to a point where there isn't street view, the API returns an empty result (obviously).
Thank you!

Comment: I guess you could just keep trying until you don't have an empty result anymore ?

Comment: I think it was too much expensive. It could repeat the request infinitely.

Comment: I guess you would have to cap the number of requests.

Answer (score 0):

First way, you can store some locations and get a random point. Second way, you can create coordinates randomly but you can end up in an ocean when doing reverse geocoding. If that happens, it will return a `"G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS" (602)` result. So it can take many requests to determine one spot.

Comment: For the first way I can't store some locations because I want to cover the entire world. For the second way, as it could repeat the request infinitely.

Comment: You can give it 5 tries for example and if still fails you can show one of your stored locations to make sure and not to cause infinite requests.

Comment: Thank you. It will work well after many requests. Maybe there aren't other solutions.